# Sometimes iPhone simulator is provided with non-iPhone web content. How to fix this?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, safari, webview, ios-simulator

I'm pretty sure, that there were times, when I ran iOS Simulator, pointed Safari to some website and Safari was loading a iPhone-specific webpage. However recently it started to load content for desktop browsers, I'm quite sure, it's for plain Safari, not mobile one. iOS Simulator is pretending to be an iPhone with user-agent string like

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3
```

When I put this string as user-agent string into desktop Safari and load, say, SO website, I can see non-mobile version, when I remove `Simulator` substring, I can see mobile-optimized SO main page.

I've no idea, what have happened, but I'd like to know, how to fix it, since I've spent a whole day catching a bug with JavaScript, and i realized that I was debugging on very different DOM.